# methods of Underscore.js in parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, underscore.js

I am trying to retrieve random 200 objects from the array returned to me by query.find() method. First i tried to implement all random number generation and all . And just now i got introduced to underscore.js method "_.sample" . 
But something is going wrong. I dont have much knowledge of underscore.js. So if someone could help that will be great. 
When i try to sun _.sample method it give me the error :

```
TypeError: Object function (e){if(e instanceof T)return e;if(!(this instanceof T))return new T(e);this._wrapped=e} has no method 'sample'
```

Someone please explain what exactly this error is. I tried searching but didn't get explanatory content. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code :

```
var queryPhrases = new Parse.Query("Phrases");
queryPhrases.select("phraseId");
queryPhrases.find().then(function(phrases){
        var arrayOfUnused = _.sample(phrases,request.params.count);
        user.add("usedPhrases",arrayOfUnused);
        user.save();
        response.success(arrayOfUnused) ;
 });
```

Comment: Post the code that caused the error.

Comment: You need to post the code that's producing that error in your question

Comment: Sample was introduced in 1.5.2. So check that the underscore.js script is included before your code and the version number.

Comment: I have written var _ = require('underscore'); at the top. Do i need to mention the version or something ?

Comment: Due to the fact that underscorejs isn't embed in Parse Cloud code ;)

Comment: UnderscoreJS is indeed embedded in Parse Cloud Code: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide/#cloud-code-modules-underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys for your responses. I couldn't find the reason or the solution to run _.sample in my code. So i implemented it the other way. Here's what i did.

```
var arrayOfUnused = _.first(_.shuffle(phrases),request.params.count);
```

This works. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Parse Cloud Code includes an outdated version of Underscore, but frustratingly, I can't find anything stating which version. While Underscore no longer ships with the Parse Javascript SDK as of v1.6.0 (late 2015), previously it had only used UnderscoreJS v1.4.4 (early 2013), so I'd expect Cloud Code to be using something from around then.

Adding the latest Underscore source to your Cloud Code is always an option, and then `require` it like any other of your own files.

Alternatively, I used the following to show a list of functions available in the included Underscore Cloud Code module.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var availableFunctions = _.functions(_);
console.log('Available Underscore Functions: ' + JSON.stringify(availableFunctions));
```